# Implicit conversion from enumeraion type warning

Tags: iphone, xcode, implicit-conversion, uicontrolevents

Xcode is now throwing up a warning sign on a previously OK line of code.

```
[_slider2 setThumbImage:thumbImage2Pressed forState:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Gives the warning:

"Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIControlEvents' to different enumeration type 'UIControlStat' (aka 'enum UIControlState')

What to do??

Answer (score 3):

`UISlider` Method:

```
- (void)setThumbImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

accept `forState` an `UIConstrolState`, not an `UIControlEvents`.

Maybe you might try this:

```
[_slider2 setThumbImage:thumbImage2Pressed forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

or another `UIControlState`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but while it explains very well what's gone wrong, it doesn't solve the issue for me. I am already using the controlStateNormal for the slider button image in its normal state... and none of the other UIControlStates work for when the slider is pressed...